# ORM Core-Data: map tables from the database to classes in code

Tags: sql, swift, macos, core-data, orm

I was given a task where I need to do an **object-relational mapping** for the tables in the database that already exists, and make the objects in my code based on that database. So afterwards I am able to save the objects from code into the database. I was given the ".bak" file of the database that already has all of it's tables and fields created, and based on that I should create objects in my code.

I am confused by the task, since my understanding of ORM goes the opposite way, meaning that the objects from the code should be mapped to the tables in the database, not vice versa.

How should I do the ORM from the tables in the database to the objects in code?
I am doing this in Swift, and I have the database ".bak" backup file.

**EDIT**

Is there an efficient way to map tables from the database to classes (objects) in Swift? Could Swift's `Core Data` do this?

Comment: Dealing with ORMs can work in both ways: you can create classes for existing tables, or create classes that ORM will automatically create tables (while not all ORMs have this ability).